# Drupal hook_cron execution order

Tags: drupal, cron, hook

What order does Drupal execute it's _cron hooks? It is important for a certain custom module I am developing and can't seem to find any documentation on it on the web. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drupal executes all of its hooks in the order based off of module weight. Module weight defaults to 0, and the secondary ordering is alphabetical by module name:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_list/6

Comment: UPDATE system SET weight='N' WHERE name='my_module'. It's a common practice for modules that need later execution to place that in their hook_install(), but you can manually do that just as easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect and adjust the cron execution orders with the [Supercron](https://www.drupal.org/project/supercron) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> SuperCron is a complete replacement for Drupal's built-in Cron functionality. It allows you to:
>
> - See the list of all Cron hooks found in the enabled modules
> - Change the order in which cron hooks are called
> - Disable certain hooks
> - Run the tasks you choose in parallel, so that cron tasks will be executed all at once rather than one after the other
> - Identify the exceptions raised by individual hooks
> - Call hooks individually on demand (great for identifying problems)
> - Keep executing cron hooks that follow an exception, limiting the damage to only one module
> - Measure the time it takes for a cron hook to execute (we display the last call timings and the average timings)
> - Capture any output generated by the hooks
> - Change the way Cron behaves when the site is under load (this optional feature requires Throttle to be enabled)
> - Limit the IP addresses that may be allowed to call your cron scripts

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 you have to rearrange modules' implementation order in [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.5.x):

```
function YOUR_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {

  // Move our hook_cron() implementation to the end of the list.
  if ($hook == 'cron') {
    $group = $implementations['YOUR_MODULE'];
    unset($implementations['YOUR_MODULE']);
    $implementations['YOUR_MODULE'] = $group;
  }
}
```

If you'd like to call your `hook_cron` first:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {

  // Move our hook_cron() implementation to the top of the list.
  if ($hook == 'cron') {
    $group = $implementations['YOUR_MODULE'];
    $implementations = [
      'YOUR_MODULE' => $group,
    ] + $implementations;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks execution is determinate from the weight of the module implementing them; the weightier module will be executed for last.